# With an AMD card, can I force V-Sync only for Rage?

Tags: pc, technical-issues, rage

So, Rage recently got unlocked for EU territories, and the first thing I noticed once I started playing is an awful lot of screen tearing.

I heard that forcing V-Sync (since sadly there's no option within Rage to turn it on) solves the issue, and it certainly did the trick for me.

However, I couldn't find a way to have forced V-Syncing turned on just for Rage. I am currently using an AMD card, but I seem to recall that when I was using an Nvidia card there were options for performing tweaks on a per-application basis by creating some sorts of application profiles. Sadly, I couldn't find anything similar in the Catalyst Control Center.

So, is there such an option buried somewhere inside the Catalyst Control Center? Is there some sort of **trustworthy** third party tool that could help me with this? Maybe there is some secret configuration file for Rage where I can turn on V-Sync instead?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of latest patch, V-Sync has now been added to the game options.

> The new "VSync" option in the video settings menu allows you to remove
>   screen tearing. There are three options: ON, OFF and SMART.

[Source](http://store.steampowered.com/news/6464/)

Note: See [edit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/31872/revisions) for previous solutions.

Comment: Actually, I managed to force V-sync globally through CCC and was looking for something more selective. The launch option you provided hit the spot, though.

Comment: @Aubergine Ah, I'm sorry, I misread your question a bit. That's what I get for being tired <.<

Comment: I'll just mention that the latest patch added an option to set V-Sync from inside the game, so there is no longer a need to force it externally or supply launch parameters.

Comment: Whereas, SMART mode requires that dynamic V-Sync is supported by the GPU drivers. If not, and you choose SMART, then it will turn V-Sync off altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a trustworthy third party tool. Check out **RadeonPro**.

http://www.radeonpro.info/download/

It has a SLEW of options you can configure, add, or override per game.